# Почему при использовании свойства box-shadow вышла тонкая светлая обводка вокруг элемента?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему при использовании свойства `box-shadow` вышла тонкая светлая обводка вокруг элемента?

```css
.form-sort__radio {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 500px;
}
.form-sort__radio-input {
  display: none;
}
.form-sort__radio::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #b8b8b8;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.form-sort__radio-input:checked + .form-sort__radio::before {
  background: #000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #fff, inset 0 0 100px #b8b8b8;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-sort__radio-input" type="radio" name="site" value="adaptive" id="adaptive">
<label for="adaptive" class="form-sort__radio">Адаптивная</label>

<input class="form-sort__radio-input" type="radio" name="site" value="fixed" id="fixed">
<label for="fixed" class="form-sort__radio">Фиксированная</label>

<input class="form-sort__radio-input" type="radio" name="site" value="rubber" id="retina">
<label for="retina" class="form-sort__radio">Резиновая</label>
```

[Пример на codepen.](http://codepen.io/Vavilkin/pen/aBGdrB)

Answer (score 1):

По тому что box-shadow задает две внутренние тени, белого цвета и серого, поменьше белого идет первая от внутреннего края элемента и вторая серая побольше идет после нее.